# Prototype cell + image + delegate

Tags: swift, image, uitableview, delegates, cell

So this is what happened: I created a tableView and delegated some stuff to it from another controller. The textLabels from the cells are working fine, but whenever I add `cell.imageView?.image`, all cells change to that specific image.

Any ideas on how to fix it? The textLabels are static but the images are not.

Here I receive the image to the tableView:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell!
    let row = indexPath.row
    let titulo = arrayInfo[row]
    let image = imgR
    cell.textLabel!.text = titulo
    cell.imageView?.image = image

    return cell
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "add") {
        let view = segue.destinationViewController as! EsseVaiPassar
            view.delegate = self
            view.delegateimg = self
    }
}
```

and here I pass it from the controller to the other one with the tableView:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        imagemRecebida.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        imagemRecebida.image = pickedImage

        delegateimg?.passImage(pickedImage!)
        print("IMAGE PICKED: \(pickedImage)")

        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is working as intended. For your textview, you are asking the value `arrayInfo[row]`. So for each cell as the `indexPath.row` changes the respective element from the array is displayed in the text field.

But for your image, it is just a single image and not an array. You aren't using `indexPath.row` to select a particular image.

To add different images to your tableView, just create an array of image like you have created an array of `String`. Just implement the logic you have implemented for the textView `cell.imageView?.image = image[indexPath.row]`

To add image only to the first cell and leave the remaining cells blank use this

```
if indexPath.row == 0
{
    cell.imageView?.image = image
}
```

Comment: Works nice and smooth. Thank you!

Comment: Also, do you know any nice online database that I could use to create users? I just saw that Parse is going to be shunted down =(

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.  Fear not, Google is your friend :)

Answer (score 0):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath' you have this code:

```
...
let image = imgR
cell.textLabel!.text = titulo
cell.imageView?.image = image
...
```

You are assigning `imgR` to the `image` constant, then you are assigning `image` to `imageView?.image`, so every cell will get the image stored in the variable `imgR`.

If you have multiple images, you need to put logic to pull the correct image for the correct row (usually an array of items).